# How to Compute or Find an Upper Bound for the Diameter of a Convex Set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, set-valued-analysis

> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be an $n$-dimensional bounded hyperrectangle, and consider a
>   $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries.
>
> Given set $\mathcal{R}$ and matrix $A$, I want to compute or find an upper
>   bound for the diameter of the set $\mathcal{X}$ defined by  the set-valued
>   integral \begin{eqnarray*} \mathcal{X} = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}
> \exp(tA)\:\mathcal{R}\:\mathrm{d}t, \qquad 0<a<b. \end{eqnarray*}

**Trouble:** $\mathcal{X}$ is a convex set but it is not clear to me whether it is a polytope.

To see this, recall the definition of point-to-set function: $$\int_{a}^{b}F(t)\mathrm{d}t = \displaystyle\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\sum_{i=\lfloor a/\Delta\rfloor}^{\lfloor b/\Delta\rfloor}\Delta F(i\Delta),$$ where the summation inside the limit is a Minkowski sum.

This leads us to $\displaystyle\sum_{i}\Delta \exp(i\Delta)\mathcal{R}$.

Each term in this sum is a (different) linear transformation of $\mathcal{R}$, hence the sum is a polytope but it is not clear to me if the limit can smooth the vertices out.

Even if the algebraic description of $\mathcal{X}$ is not possible, the diameter or a bound on its diameter will do for my purpose.

Comment: Couldn't you just compute the diameter of the approximating sum-set (which is presumably a polytope ?) and then hope that in the limit, this will approach the diameter of $\mathcal X$ ?

Comment: Well, I have been thinking along those lines. I know that $\text{diam}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i}\right) \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i} \text{diam}\left(\right)$. But I am unsure of the following: if a convex set is parameterized by a scalar, then can the diameter and limit w.r.t that scalar be interchanged? If yes, then how to formally prove this?